# how to integrate cashfree payment gateway in ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment-gateway, payment-method, cashfree

i want to integrate cashfree payment gateway in ruby on rails, my project is built on ruby on rails at backend and React.js on froentend
help me to integrate cashfree with checkout page of cashfree

1. user comes click make payment
2. a cashfree window opens where user enter bank detail
3. user can pay through many way like:  upi, barcode, cards, internet banking, etc

gem cashfree but doc of that not available